# How to list group of words?

Tags: python

I have a column which lists:

| Column 1 |
| --- |
| group A - group B - group C - group D |
| type A - type B - type C - type D |
| colour A - colour B - colour C - colour D |

How can I separate them into 4 different columns ie

| Column 1 |
| --- |
| group A |
| type A |
| colour A |

| Column 2 |
| --- |
| group B |
| type B |
| colour B |

| Column 3 |
| --- |
| group C |
| type C |
| colour C |

| Column 4 |
| --- |
| group D |
| type D |
| colour D |

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Is your source a flat list, a CSV file, a pandas dataframe, or some other data format?

Comment: Please put some Python specific infromation in your question. What exactly is your input data (file, string, dataframe) and what output data do you expect?

Comment: My apologies, I am very new to python, learning it myself via youtube. So do bear with me for being a little lost. lol

Comment: It is a dataframe

Comment: raw data and data frame, and a xlsx file

Comment: Okay, this is how I like the output to look like: https://quasar-reports.uk/dgqt567eeq/2021/02/Capture.jpg

Comment: Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution working :

```py
import pandas as pd

#Initialize a dataframe same as yours
article = {'ID': ['123','456','782'],
            'Location': ["PO9","PO10","PO20"],
            'Reporter': ["Jhon Smith","Mary White","David Mason"],
            'Date': ["20/12/2020","13/05/2020","04/05/2019"],
            'Organisation': ["Best Eastern","Great Supply","Speedy Courrier"],
            'Department': ["Finance","Marketing","Logistic"],
            'Tags': ["Payement - Transfer - Delay - Chase","Design - Artwork - Demo - Service","KPI - Performance - Review - Planning"]
            }

df = pd.DataFrame(article)

#df is Your Dataframe and that is where we start working with it

Tags_column= df['Tags'].values.tolist()

Tags_column = [element.split(" - ") for element in Tags_column]

Results = [[line[index] for line in Tags_column] for index in range(len(Tags_column[0]))]

for index,tag in enumerate(Results):
    df["tag_"+str(index)] = tag

#Show the final dataframe
print(df)
"""
    ID Location     Reporter        Date     Organisation Department                                   Tags     tag_0        tag_1   tag_2     tag_3
0  123      PO9   Jhon Smith  20/12/2020     Best Eastern    Finance    Payement - Transfer - Delay - Chase  Payement     Transfer   Delay     Chase
1  456     PO10   Mary White  13/05/2020     Great Supply  Marketing      Design - Artwork - Demo - Service    Design      Artwork    Demo   Service
2  782     PO20  David Mason  04/05/2019  Speedy Courrier   Logistic  KPI - Performance - Review - Planning       KPI  Performance  Review  Planning
"""
```

Comment: Hi Anatole, I tried but it didn't work. Help! I need the output to look like this https://quasar-reports.uk/dgqt567eeq/2021/02/Capture.jpg

Comment: This should  convert your column into a list ```Column_1 = yourDataFrame['Tags'].values.tolist() ```

Comment: I updated the answer it should now be what you were looking for !

Comment: Where is the location of Column_1 please?

Comment: What do you mean ? I just initialize it as the tag column. I have changed my script to replace Column 1 with Tag Column, it should be clearer.

Comment: Thanks so much Anatole. What about if the data is selected from a xlsx file, how do I address "article"? Obviously if there are 10,000 rows then it would not be possible to list all of them under "article".

Comment: Look [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) to see the doc of the ```pandas.read_excel``` function. It should be what you want.

Comment: Thanks Anatole. Tag_0, Tag_1, Tag_2, Tag_3 have worked. However, all the other columns: ID, Location, Reporter, Date, Organisation and Department have now disappeared in the output! Thought I have rejoined the new columns back but obviously not. Can you help please?

Comment: I did it like this:     Tags_column = df["Tags"].values.tolist()   |    
      Tags_column = [str(element).split(" - ") for element in Tags_column]

# Now that the Tags have been split into a list of lists, turn them back into a DataFrame
Results = pd.DataFrame (Tags_column)

#Rename the columns so that each starts with "tag_"
Results.columns = ["tag_" + str(column_name) for column_name in Results.columns]

# Merge Results back onto the Tags df
df = pd.concat([df,Results],axis=1)

#Show the final dataframe
Print(df)